# How to sum all invidual integers (parts of integers) within a list of integers?

Tags: python, list, integer

In other words, I have a list like this `[10, 11, 22, 6, 4, 9]` and I want it to add up all the individual integers. So, `1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 6 + 4 + 9`.

I have tried using the `sum` function and other various suggestions online and I'm still lost. What could I do to break up the integers so I can sum the individual parts? Slicing? Indexing? Happy to answer any questions!!!

Answer (score 7):

you can iterate through each integer as a string and get the sum of each part of it.

```
>>> lst = [10, 11, 22, 6, 4, 9]
>>> sum([int(i) for x in lst for i in str(x)])
26
```